# What're the Singular Values of $A+kI$? Is there a way to understand it intuitively?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

So in a homework problem during last semester, I remember the solution using a property that was similar to $\sigma_i(A+kI) = \sigma_i(A) + k$. However, I can't find this property anywhere. I'm not sure if it assumes anything about the matrix $A$ other than it being square. I understand why $\lambda_i(A+kI) = \lambda_i(A) + k$, so I imagine there's something similar for singular values of a generic matrix A? I was also wondering if anyone had any intuition, preferably geometric, as to *why* these statements are true.

Thanks.

Comment: The largest singular value is a norm. So, just as $|-2+1| \neq 2 +1$, you cannot expect the same for the singular values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that this result is true. Because taking

$A=\begin{bmatrix}
 1& 1 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$ and $k=1$ we get $A+kI$=

$A+I=\begin{bmatrix}
 2& 1 \\
0 & 2 \\\end{bmatrix}$ . But the singular values of $A$ are $\sigma_{1}=1.6180$ and $\sigma_{2}=0.6180$.

The singular values of $A+I$ are $\sigma_{1}=2.5616$ and $\sigma_{2}=1.5616$.

It is clear that $\sigma_{i}(A+I)\neq\,\sigma_{i}(A)+1$